# "QuickLookUIService" Using Significant Energy

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, high-sierra

After macOS High Sierra upgrade I noticed "QuickLookUIService" is always in "Using Significant Energy" list. Has anyone have same problem? And is there any suggestion about this?

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

Version 10.13.1

[image: QuickLookUIService]

Comment: This is normal to generate quick look thumbnails and process files in the background. Do you experience this after letting the machine run without sleep for several hours or overnight connected to power?

Comment: Yes. But I tried to restart and it's gone. I guess when I quick look something, it will stuck again. If it will not I will let you know.

Comment: I have the exact same machine, but running Mojave, and I've seen this happen a few times. Most recently when I noticed this pop up, my battery dropped to 63% after 45 minutes of use, with nothing else open other than Safari. I don't know what causes it, but logging out and back in seemed to fix it. Just a process running haywire for whatever reason.

Comment: @daGUY I installed gfxCardStatus app and getting notifications when mac switched graphic card. And I force quit the QuickLookUIService and it's returns back normal.

Comment: quicklookuiservice was "fixed" in high sierra.  that means that it has lots and lots of bugs.  you'll see all sorts of problems with this little program.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Here's a suggestion that worked for me, it involves creating a daemon that will kill the service QuickLookUIService every 5600 seconds (you can tune this setting).
Whole answer here with the daemon code is here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8506070

The one that I had to Force Quit everytime was QuickLookUIService (Spotlight). I'm running Mojave 10.14.6 on a Mid 2012 Macbook Pro 15' non-retina.

In a nutshell, this service is not responding using significant energy and avoiding switching to the integrated graphics, draining your battery until you kill it.

Comment: Edited trying to stay inside the guidelines.